# Why does mockito report error on thenReturn() in java 7 but not in java 6

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Mockito reports unfinished stubbing error when mocking `client.getPrograms()` which should return `SortedSet<Program>`. Interesting part is that it does so only when using Java 7 and not when using Java 6.

Here's the code that triggers error when mocking `client.getPrograms()`:

```
private void prepareScheduleChangePreconditions() {
    Client client = mock(Client.class);
    TimeTable tt = BuilderUtil.buildTable(AcceleratedScheduleTimeTable.Schedule.NORMAL, "08:00");
    when(clientRepository.findByCode(anyString())).thenReturn(client);
    //Error is reported for next line of code
    when(client.getPrograms()).thenReturn(new TreeSet<Program>(Collections.singleton(program)));
    when(event.getTimeTable()).thenReturn(tt);      
}
```

Here's the error output:

```
Tests in error:
  testExampleScheduleChangeNotify1(com.example.service.impl.ExampleServiceImplTest):
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.example.service.impl.ExampleServiceImplTest.prepareScheduleChangePreconditions(ExampleServiceImplTest.java:134)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

Method is not final. Any help or clues would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

As per Mike B request, I managed to isolate this into simpler test case that fails in Java 7.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {

    @Mock
    Program program;

    private void preparePreconditions() {
        Client client = mock(Client.class);
        when(client.getPrograms()).thenReturn(new TreeSet<Program>(Collections.singleton(program)));
    }

    public static class Client {
        public SortedSet<Program> getPrograms() {
            return new TreeSet<Program>();
        }
    }

    public static class Program implements Comparable<Program> {
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Program program) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        preparePreconditions();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Strangely enough, it works if I do it this way:

```
TreeSet<Program> programs = new TreeSet<Program>();
programs.add(program);
when(client.getPrograms()).thenReturn(programs);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `doReturn().when()` instead of `when().thenReturn()`? I've found it to be less flaky.

Comment: Well, I've "fixed" it using thenAnswer instead of thenReturn but was wondering what's the reason it doesn't work with thenReturn - am I missing something?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the classes you're mocking.

Comment: @Mike B `doReturn(new TreeSet<Program>(Collections.singleton(program))).when(client.getPrograms());` results with same error

Comment: @Mike B I updated the question with complete test class and mocked classes that cause the error.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that what is really happening here is more than one mock method invocation in single `when(...).then(...)` statement.

Consider following example:

```
when(program.getName()).thenReturn(String.valueOf(program.compareTo(null)));
```

It returns the same exception that You have. It is because there are two methods invoked on mock: `getName()` and `compareTo()` in single `when(...).thenReturn(...)` statement.

Also in [this page](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing) (the mockito documentation) You can read that:

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).

Therefore mockito has to have some mechanism for detecting what to do (return) for which invocation on some mocked object.

In Your example second invocation is made by `new TreeSet<>(Collections.singleton(program))` statement, because TreeSet constructor is using `compareTo()` method of Your mock.

It seems that implementation of TreeSet changed from java 6 to java 7. That is why it could have worked earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't actually answer your question, but remember the prime directive of mocking:

1. Mock roles, not objects

In practice, this means that mocking a class (i.e. not an interface) is a blinking red warning sign that something is wrong with your design.

If you have no control over the code you're interfacing with (e.g., it is a third-party library or legacy software), I like to wrap the class in an interface and mock that.  As a bonus, this also allows you do rename poorly-named methods (and classes) in the other code.  From your example, what "programs" does the client return?  Is it the set of active programs, running programs, what? Let's assume that it is the set of active programs:

```
public interface Programs {
    SortedSet<Program> active();
}

class SimpleClientWrapper implements Programs {
    private final Client wrapped;

    SimpleClientWrapper(Client c) { wrapped = c; }

    public SortedSet<Program> active() { return wrapped.getPrograms(); }
}
```

If this feels like too much work (and I admit that sometimes it is overkill), another possibility, if the method(s) you want to mock are non-final, is to temporarily override them in your test:

```
Client client = new Client() {
    @Override
    public SortedSet<Program> getPrograms() {
        return new TreeSet<Program>(Collections.singleton(program));
    }
};
```

I sometimes use this approach to override error handlers and such.

Comment: I am perhaps abusing convenience of Mockito's thenReturn() chaining instead of using concrete test instances here since aforementioned classes here are data-modeling classes (and when I look it now, I didn't really need a mock there). I disagree on creating an interface for every class though (especially DTO type class) if the only other implementation would perhaps be a mock in a unit test.

Comment: I don't mean that you should have an interface for every class; DTO-type (value) classes, as you mention, are a typical case where you don't need an interface; but as you've realized, you shouldn't mock them either.  My point was more to show useful implementation techniques for dealing with legacy code.

Comment: Value types should be constructed as values in tests. If they are inconvenient to create them you should write a test helper factory function which can create the values conveniently.